# NSFieldEditor / NSTextView: set Dictionary for autocomplete

Tags: objective-c, autocomplete, nstextfield, nstextview

I invoke autocomplete on a NSTextField by using it's `field editor`:

```
-(void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSTextView *fieldEditor = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"NSFieldEditor"];
    NSString *newValue = [fieldEditor string];
    BOOL textDidNotChange = [lastTypedStreetValue isEqualToString:newValue];

    if( textDidNotChange ){
        return;
    }
    else {
        lastTypedStreetValue = [newValue copy];    
        [fieldEditor complete:nil];
    }
}
```

How do I set the dictionary for the autocomplete of this `NSTextField`?

= How do I set the words that pop up as suggestions in the autocomplete?

I have an `NSArray` of words I need to use.

Comment: Is `NSComboBox` what you're looking for? Or take a look at `NSControlTextEditingDelegate`.

Comment: Thank you Willeke, `NSControlTextEditingDelegate` came to the rescue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Willeke, the solution looks as follows:

```
 -(NSArray *)  control:(NSControl*) control
              textView:(NSTextView*) textView
           completions:(NSArray*) words
   forPartialWordRange:(NSRange) charRange
   indexOfSelectedItem:(NSInteger*) index
{
    NSArray *array = [methodThatCreatesTheWordList];
    return array;
}
```